# What is the regular expression to find a string in log files with the following format: "Failures: [!0]"?

Tags: regex, vi

I'm looking for the regular expression to find failures in a log file.
The format is "Failures: " following the number of error, a digit not zero

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like `Failures:[1-9]\d*`

Comment: you tagged with vi, you might mean `vim`? do you want to filter your current buffer with the regex? what role does vim play here?

Comment: @Kent, I use vi/vim to open the log files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
"Failures:\s+[1-9]\d*"
```

Comment: Nah, `"Failures: \d+"` matches `0`. See my answer in the comments

Comment: Oh, it can't be zero. I didn't undrerstand that from the question. So, thank you.

Comment: No worries Artyom, I misread questions all the time. Hey why use `{1,}` instead of `+`?

Comment: Indeed, why? =)) Fixed.

Comment: Just found some upvotes in my pocket, so +1 for persistence :)

Answer (score 1):

this would be what you are looking for:

```
Failures:\s*[1-9]\d*
```

btw, you may want to know that in character class, the `not` notation is `^`, not `!`.

E.g. `[^a-zA-Z]` means **not** letters.

Comment: We're twins, that was my comment but I hadn't noticed the spaces. :) +1